# Protractor test

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests

I need some help.
This is fragment of my code, i can't return boolean from it("present or not")
, so everything is working incorrectly. where I was mistaken?

```
describe("first TEST", function () {

    var boolean, parsingAllProfiles, getRandomProfile, randomProfile;

    it("present or not", function () {
        freelan.notFreelancersFound.isPresent().then(function (result) {
            **return boolean = result;**
        })
    })

    if (boolean) {
        console.log("NOTHING!!!!!")
    } else {

        it("array of profiles", function() {
            Promise.resolve(freelan.parsingAllProfilePage()).then(function (profiles) {
                var arrForCheck = freelan.cloneArray(profiles);
                freelan.checkKeywordInProfile(arrForCheck, params.keyword);
                return randomProfile = profiles[Math.floor(Math.random() * profiles.length)];
            })
        });        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do with the boolean, but here's what it might look like in a test with chained promises.

```
describe("first TEST", function () {

    var boolean, parsingAllProfiles, getRandomProfile, randomProfile;

    it("present or not", function () {
        freelan.notFreelancersFound.isPresent().then(function(result) {
            if (result) {
                freelan.parsingAllProfilePage().then(function(profiles) {
                    var arrForCheck = freelan.cloneArray(profiles);
                    expect(freelan.checkKeywordInProfile(arrForCheck, params.keyword).toBe(true);
                });
            } else {
                console.log("NOTHING!!!!!");
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: thank you very much. later i understood, that condition must be "inside chain".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the library in question, but promise-based code async, meaning that this inner code `**return boolean = result;**` won't run until *after* other things in the main function.

```
it("present or not", function () {
      freelan.notFreelancersFound.isPresent().then(function (result) {
          **return boolean = result;**
      })
})
```

What you really need to do is read up on Promises and learn how to chain then.  If you return a promise from your test, it will wait for that promise to resolve before moving onto the next test.

Comment: this is my first big test script on protactor.